# How to get rid of the html encoded characters in wordpress for a facebook share?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I am trying to share articles via buttons on my wordpress blog, but all the characters in facebook are encoded with html code such as

```
<meta property="og:title" content="R&#xe8;gle numero 1, ne jamais mettre sa main sur un &amp;laquo;&amp;nbsp;aquarium &#xe0; requins&amp;nbsp;&amp;raquo; !" />
```

Is there a simple way to get rid of that code and instead have a good title/ description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php):

```
<meta property="og:title" 
    content="<?php echo html_entity_decode('R&#xe8;gle numero 1, ne jamais mettre sa main sur un &amp;laquo;&amp;nbsp;aquarium &#xe0; requins&amp;nbsp;&amp;raquo; !'); ?>">
```